# Applying 'WHERE' predicate to GEOGRAPHY data type column in SNOWFLAKE

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, geospatial

can anyone answer if we can filter out the geography type data in SNOWFLAKE using WHERE predicate?

In the image shown, I just want polygon type entries.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BNiV3.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible to use WHERE clause and some functions to filter the data. Have you checked the functions that you can compare geography objects?

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions-geospatial.html

```
create or replace table geo_table (lat1 float, lng1 float, lat2 float, lng2 float, lat3 float, lng3 float);
insert into geo_table values
    (0, 10, 10, 10, 10, 0);

select st_makepolygon(to_geography('LINESTRING(' 
          || lat1 || ' ' || lng1 || ','
          || lat2 || ' ' || lng2 || ','
          || lat3 || ' ' || lng3 || ','
          || lat1 || ' ' || lng1 || ' )')) as result
from geo_table
where ST_WITHIN( st_makepoint( 8, 8 ), result ) ; -- returns true as the point is inside of the polygon                                                   

+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                          RESULT                                           |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| { "coordinates": [ [ [ 0, 10 ], [ 10, 10 ], [ 10, 0 ], [ 0, 10 ] ] ], "type": "Polygon" } |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Wow ... that's cool ... have not played much with geo but that's example shows a really nice technique to do some powerful stuff. Great answer thanks :-)